# merge two yaml files in python

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have two yaml files as mentioned below

test1.yaml

```
resources:
  server_group_1:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 5] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 5] } ]

  server_group_2:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 8] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 8] } ]
output:
  check_1:
    description: Name of the instance
    value: { get_attr: [check_1, vname] }
```

test2.yaml

```
resources:
  server_group_4:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 4] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 4] } ]

  server_group_9:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 7] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 7] } ]
output:
  check_6:
    description: Name of the instance
    value: { get_attr: [check_6, vname] }
```

I want to merge this two files and create a new output file ,so I use pyyaml the order is getting changed posted same in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418485/improper-output-with-pyyaml)

Can someone help to merge these files without changing the order?
Final yaml should be like this

final.yaml

```
resources:
  server_group_1:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 5] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 5] } ]

  server_group_2:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 8] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 8] } ]

  server_group_4:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 4] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 4] } ]

  server_group_9:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 7] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 7] } ]
output:
  check_1:
    description: Name of the instance
    value: { get_attr: [check_1, vname] }

  check_6:
    description: Name of the instance
    value: { get_attr: [check_6, vname] }
```

**Updated**

I am able to merge files using ruamel.yaml ... here goes the sample code to update resources

code:

```
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
#Load the yaml files
with open('/test1.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
with open('/test2.yaml') as fp:
    data1 = yaml.load(fp)
#Add the resources from test2.yaml to test1.yaml resources
for i in data1['resources']:
    print i,data1['resources'][i]
    data['resources'].update({i:data1['resources'][i]})
#create a new file with merged yaml
yaml.dump(data,file('/tmp/lal.yaml', 'w'))
```

Comment: After attempt I came here ...I tried with pyyaml but due to nested it is not giving proper output and order is also changing

Comment: @anthon has suggested to use ruamel.yaml will try using that

Comment: @mkrieger1 worked with ruamel.yaml ... My request dont be in hurry to downvote by saying not trying .....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below sample code worked well for me to merge two yaml file

```
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
#Load the yaml files
with open('/test1.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
with open('/test2.yaml') as fp:
    data1 = yaml.load(fp)
#Add the resources from test2.yaml to test1.yaml resources
for i in data1['resources']:
    print i,data1['resources'][i]
    data['resources'].update({i:data1['resources'][i]})
#create a new file with merged yaml
yaml.dump(data,file('/tmp/lal.yaml', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution is to use HiYaPyCo (https://pypi.org/project/HiYaPyCo/), which implements a merge preserving an order of elements.

```
import hiyapyco

yaml1 = """resources:
  server_group_1:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 5] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 5] } ]

  server_group_2:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 8] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 8] } ]
output:
  check_1:
    description: Name of the instance
    value: { get_attr: [check_1, vname] }"""

yaml2 = """resources:
  server_group_4:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 4] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 4] } ]

  server_group_9:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name: { get_param: [server_groups, 7] }
      policies: [ { get_param: [server_group_types, 7] } ]
output:
  check_6:
    description: Name of the instance
    value: { get_attr: [check_6, vname] }"""

merged_yaml = hiyapyco.load([yaml1, yaml2], method=hiyapyco.METHOD_MERGE)
print(hiyapyco.dump(merged_yaml))
```

Output:

```
resources:
  server_group_1:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name:
        get_param: [server_groups, 5]
      policies:
      - get_param: [server_group_types, 5]
  server_group_2:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name:
        get_param: [server_groups, 8]
      policies:
      - get_param: [server_group_types, 8]
  server_group_4:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name:
        get_param: [server_groups, 4]
      policies:
      - get_param: [server_group_types, 4]
  server_group_9:
    type: OS::Nova::ServerGroup
    properties:
      name:
        get_param: [server_groups, 7]
      policies:
      - get_param: [server_group_types, 7]
output:
  check_1:
    description: Name of the instance
    value:
      get_attr: [check_1, vname]
  check_6:
    description: Name of the instance
    value:
      get_attr: [check_6, vname]
```